# .LIST file into Azure table storage

Tags: azure, imdb

I have some .LIST files from IMDB with data on movie, actors, etc. I need to get this data into Azure's table storage, but I have no idea how to go about this.

Does anybody know how to do this, or if this is even possible?

Answer (score 2):

Write some code to do it.

If you're a .NET developer, you'll need to write an application - Console Application should be fine - using the WindowsAzure.Storage Nuget package. Write code to open the .list file, read and parse the contents. I'm guessing the format will be documented somewhere on IMDB.

To get it into Table Storage, you need to either derive a class from TableEntity with properties representing the fields from IMDB, or contruct DynamicTableEntity instances with the data. Then you insert them into a Table using `CloudTable.Execute(TableOperation.Insert(entity))`.

See more here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj732635(v=azure.10).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj732635%28v=azure.10%29.aspx)